# How to update Laravel command?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I used this command for installing Laravel:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

For creating a project I use :

```
laravel new project
```

Today Laravel 5.7 was released, and I'm looking for installing it using the `laravel` command but I couldn't do it. Instead, a new laravel project was created with Laravel 5.6.33. I need some help.

**Note:** I can create a project with Laravel 5.7 with this command, but I need to update my required Laravel and make a project with laravel 5.7 by using the laravel command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Comment: what is problem????

Comment: I need to install latest version of laravel with laravel new blog command !

Comment: you need version 5.6??

Comment: I need version 5.7 ! I sayed to need latest version .

Comment: You probably need `composer global update` to update the `laravel` command. Given that the `laravel new project` does the same thing as `composer create-project` under the hood, I don't know why you're insistent on avoiding the `composer` method.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to globally update Laravel to the new version just run

```
composer global require laravel/installer`
```

to update globally

Comment: This is most correct answer in this topic, thanks

Comment: In my case,  I had upgraded the version of PHP I was using and had to delete my  `~/.composer/composer.lock` file and reinstall.

Answer (score 4):

Try this to update laravel installer on global level:

```
composer global update
```

Answer (score 3):

Update your laravel/framework dependency to 5.7.* in your `composer.json` file.

Run this command

```
composer update

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Laravel 5.7 Installation Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#installing-laravel), has the exact instructions for your problem.

- Install the Laravel Installer via composer: `composer global require "laravel/installer"`
- Run the command: `laravel new <project-name>`

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.7.*"
```

Comment: I'm really sorry for my bad explain , But I need to install Laravel 5.7 with 'laravel new project' command !!

Comment: and I could made with this command , But I need laravel command .